# Place the IF condition variable in a where clause in SQL select

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

So I want to display the list of my items that will be affected by the exchange rate. The select statement below shows the list of the products as well as the orginal selling price and the value test has an IF statement that computes the costofitem * exchange rate. If it is greater than the original selling price then the query should print it, if not just display null

In addition to this, the final list should not contain the NULL test values.

I have already tried adding test IS NOT NULL in the where clause but the sql server cannot recognize the function. How can I possibly display it?

**MYSQL SELECT**:

```
select 
  p.itemcode, p.itemdescription, p.sellingprice, c.exchangerate,
  IF ( cos.costofitem * c.exchangerate > p.sellingprice,
       cos.costofitem * c.exchangerate,
       NULL ) as test
from
  product p
  join supplier s on p.suppliercode = s.suppliercode
  join currency c on c.countrycode=s.countrycode
  join country co on co.countrycode=c.countrycode
  left join cost cos on cos.itemcode=p.itemcode
where
  c.countrycode = 'NZ' and s.excode = 0
group by p.itemcode
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
GS771516    UBBLE PARTY MACHINE       2175.00    37.38        NULL
GS771517    BUBBLE PARTY MACHINE JR    925.00    37.38        NULL
GS771518    TURBO BUBBLE MACHINE      1430.00    37.38        NULL
GS771989    GIANT BUBBLE WAND          435.00    37.38    747.6000
GS771999    MEGA BUBBLES              1235.00    37.38        NULL
```

**THE OUTPUT THAT I WANT**:

```
GS771989    GIANT BUBBLE WAND       435.00    37.38    747.6000
```

Comment: You must repeat the function in the WHERE clause.

Comment: The reason is that WHERE happens before SELECT. You can only select from stuff that has passed the filter, if you will. That's why WHERE doesn't know about formulas or aliases you use in SELECT. You could use an inner query to calculate and an outer query to filter on the calculation. If that's faster in your situation you'll have to measure.

Answer (score 0):

If you use LEFT JOIN, the sql get rows with empty values ( NULL ), use **INNER JOIN** for get only the rows that accomplish the consult exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Better option is that you should use join instead of left join, so that only valid rows will be fetched by query but if you want to use your query then use below one-

try below query:

```
SELECT itemcode, itemdescription, sellingprice, exchangerate, test FROM 
(SELECT p.itemcode, p.itemdescription, p.sellingprice, c.exchangerate,
IF (cos.costofitem * c.exchangerate > p.sellingprice, cos.costofitem * c.exchangerate,
NULL ) AS test
FROM product p JOIN supplier s ON p.suppliercode = s.suppliercode
JOIN currency c ON c.countrycode=s.countrycode
JOIN country co ON co.countrycode=c.countrycode
LEFT JOIN cost COS ON cos.itemcode=p.itemcode
WHERE c.countrycode = 'NZ' AND s.excode = 0
GROUP BY p.itemcode) a
WHERE test IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I already tried this one and it didn't work. Thanks tho! The user above commented that i just repeat the whole condition in the where clause

Comment: It is still not working if I do this kind of query. I think i'll just settle with adding the condition 'cos.costofitem * c.exchangerate > p.sellingprice' in the where clause. Thank you!

Comment: I have tested this query and it is working fine and excluding NULL value rows, please share which kind of problem you are getting query is not executing or NULL are not excluding.